# Tehillim: can one pray Psalm 119 for themself after having prayed for family and friends?

Tags: tefilla, tehilim-psalms, choleh-sick

After saying Psalm 119, one prays for a list of others. Is inserting one's self, after one's own list of *others'* names inappropriate to this tefillah, or is it designed for healing both self and others? From what I have gathered, Tehillim seems to be most appropriate for petitioning for others' health recovery, as seen here:
 http://www.dailytehillim.com/119Tool.aspx?Sick=True

If Tehillim is mainly designed for petitioning for others' healing, what would be the recommendation for one to pray on behalf of their own illnesses, too? It has been suggested to me that petitioning can be inserted, for example, before the final 3 brachot of the shimonei esrei.

Comment: I've edited the question for clarity according to my understanding of it. But I'm not sure I understood it correctly, so please re-edit as you see fit. You may also wish to edit in why you think including yourself in the prayer may harm its effectiveness.

Comment: i once heard a tape by Rabbi Avigdor Miller z'l where he says praying for oneself is a mitzva - you're praying for a jew.